# PHP Server to Server Window XAMPP to UBUNTU Apache

Tags: php, windows, apache

On the Ubuntu server the database, web, and php seem to be working correctly.
I copied my php application from Windows 10 XAMPP environment to my Ubuntu into the correct  directories. 
Using the Firefox on another Ubuntu it brings up the first page correctly, but when it jumps to the next php code application I get a 404 can not find file.

I can manually get the page without problem.  I must be missing something very simple.  So can you help?

I'm not a Ubuntu guru, still learn all the ins and outs.

Comment: using any frameworks? you checked the .htaccess file?

Comment: Do not have a .htaccess file.

Comment: So, create it, take a look at the Windows 10 http folder of you project, it shoud be there. BTW are you using any framework?

Comment: Neither of the Windows XAMPP have active .htaccess